# How can I disable a single navigation bar item in android studio, java

Tags: java, android, xml, navbar

How can I disable a single navigation bar item from clicking, rippling or focusing when touched or pressed (I use java)

[image: How can disable or stop the item at the middle to stop focusing or pressing]

My [image: XML] code is here

Comment: you can give the working idea from this: https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx

Comment: Instead of posting code, error messages, data, or other text as images or links, please [edit] your post to copy/paste or type the actual text directly into the post (for code, use a [code block](/editing-help#code)). [Text in images cannot be copied to reproduce the issue, and error messages in images cannot be searched](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/208273). Links may become invalid if the linked site changes.  If your code is too long to fit in the post, we have tips on [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).